# Replacing certain index value of Dataframe

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to change a certain index value of a dataframe.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
    start   stop    nested_in
0   2015-11-10 05:42:00+00:00   2015-11-10 07:22:00+00:00   -1.0
0   2015-11-10 05:42:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:09:00+00:00   0.0
0   2015-11-10 06:21:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:37:00+00:00   0.0
0   2015-11-10 06:42:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:58:00+00:00   0.0
0   2015-11-10 17:00:00+00:00   2015-11-10 21:55:00+00:00   -1.0
0   2015-11-10 17:00:00+00:00   2015-11-10 17:45:00+00:00   4.0
0   2015-11-10 17:45:00+00:00   2015-11-10 18:01:00+00:00   4.0
```

With 0's being the index.

I want to do something like this:

```
for i in range(0, df.size):
   df.index[i] = i
```

But this gives me following error

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

All I am able to do is this:

```
df.index = [i1, i2,... , i(df.size-1)]
```

So for this example:

```
df.index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The output I want is this:

```
    start   stop    nested_in
0   2015-11-10 05:42:00+00:00   2015-11-10 07:22:00+00:00   -1.0
1   2015-11-10 05:42:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:09:00+00:00   0.0
2   2015-11-10 06:21:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:37:00+00:00   0.0
3   2015-11-10 06:42:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:58:00+00:00   0.0
4   2015-11-10 17:00:00+00:00   2015-11-10 21:55:00+00:00   -1.0
5   2015-11-10 17:00:00+00:00   2015-11-10 17:45:00+00:00   4.0
6   2015-11-10 17:45:00+00:00   2015-11-10 18:01:00+00:00   4.0
```

I did some research but couldn't find a straight-up easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
indices = range(df.shape[0]) # this can be anything as long as the length is same as that of the number of rows in the dataframe
df['indices'] = indices
df = df.set_index('indices')

print df.head()
```